# Is there way to setup `primaryGroupId` for user using ldif?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, samba, ldif

I want to setup  PrimaryGroupId for user. For that purpose I've created the with content:

```
dn: CN=user_2,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=company
changetype: modify
replace: primaryGroupID
primaryGroupID: 501
```

But when I execute ldbmodify command I get the error:

```
/ # LDB_MODULES_PATH=/usr/lib/samba/ldb/ ldbmodify -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb /tmp/primary_group.ldif 
'rror: Bad ldif changetype 'modify
 at block before line 3!" on DN CN=user_2,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=company=my,DC=company
Modify failed after processing 0 records
```

Is there way to setup `primaryGroupId` for user using ldif ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
dn: CN=user_2,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=company
changetype: modify
delete: primaryGroupID
add: primaryGroupID
primaryGroupID: 501
```